# Adobe PDF issue in .net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am using `acrobatpdf.dll` in my project. The functionally is working fine but after opening the pdf, toolbar is comming and asking for save pdf, print,next, previous,zoom in, zoom out.

I don't want all these, I want only pdf without any option for security purpose.

[image]

My code is:

```
AxAcroPDF1.Visible = True
AxAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(False)
AxAcroPDF1.setPageMode("none")
AxAcroPDF1.setView("Fit")
AxAcroPDF1.src = "ASPNET.pdf"
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: This would be more about how you're viewing your PDF, nothing to do with how you create it. Have you tried, say, opening with Google Drive and see how it works there?